# Mysql Update multitable query

Tags: mysql

I have this select JOIN statement for 3 tables and I would like to know what should be the UPDATE statement.

```
SELECT candidates.CandidateName, candidates.CandidateVotes, candidates.Party, mainrace.MainRaceName, race.RaceName, candidates.win, candidates.NameOrder
FROM candidates
JOIN race ON race.RaceID = candidates.RaceID
JOIN mainrace ON mainrace.MainID = candidates.MainID
ORDER BY mainrace.MainRaceName'
```

I have something like this and I am guessing it is a mess :)

```
$sql = "update candidates set candidates.CandidateName='$CandidateName',candidates.CandidateVotes='$CandidateVotes',candidates.Party='$Party',candidates.win='$win' ,candidates.NameOrder='$NameOrder' where candidates.CandidateID=$CandidateID";
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax should be:

```
Update  candidates join ... set
```